# How to set volume in QtMultimedia/QSound in Python?

Tags: qtmultimedia

import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtMultimedia

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(**file**))

def main():
filename = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, 'Max Brhon - Cyberpunk.wav')

```
app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

QtMultimedia.QSound.play(filename)


# end in 5 seconds:
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5 * 1000, app.quit)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()